# Where to set GDK_BACKEND

Tags: arch-linux, x11, gnome

I face the following issue when using keepassxc. When click the toolbar the program closed automatically with the following error:

`Gdk-WARNING **: gdkwindow-x11.c:5573 drawable is not a native X11 window`

So I started the programm from the commandline with the variable:

`GDK_BACKEND=X11 keepassxc`

And everything is working fine.

My question now is where is the right place for `export GDK_BACKEND=X11`?

I tried the following config fils with no success:

- .profile
- .bash_profile
- .bashrc
- .xinitrc
- .xsession

My setup:

- Arch Linux
- Gnome
- Xorg

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a launcher to start the app ? If so just create a custom one: copy the original from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and modify the exec line to read `Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=X11 keepasxc blahblah` where `keepasxc blahblah` is the original value of the exec line. Double-click it, mark as trusted and you're done.

Comment: Nice idea but this isn't working. When inserting `env GDK_BACKEND=X11` it won't start and I get no error.

Comment: :) not necessarily a nice idea but just what everyone else uses to make stuff work with wayland ([example](https://github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/blob/master/linux_various/PCSX2.desktop.in)); now, why it doesn't work for you - I have no idea... if you check your journal you'll prolly find some clues

Answer (score 5):

Are you using a launcher to start the app? If so just create a custom one: copy the original from `/usr/share/applications` to `~/.local/share/applications` and modify the exec line to read `Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=X11 keepasxc blahblah` where `keepasxc blahblah` is the original value of the exec line. Double-click it, mark as trusted and you're done.

try:

```
Exec=env GDK_BACKEND=x11 ....
```

Capitals matters!